# Как отсортировать обьект массива с вложеным JSON по дате ключа?

Tags: python, json, list, сортировка, datetime

Как отсортировать обьект массива с вложеным JSON по дате ключа?

```
data = [{
  "history_date": "23.05.2021, 6:52",
  "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
},
{
  "history_date": "24.05.2021, 8:52",
  "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
},
{
  "history_date": "25.05.2021, 9:52",
  "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
}]
```

Чтобы получить в итоге тот же массив, только с сортировкой по дате.

```
data = [{
  "history_date": "25.05.2021, 9:52",
  "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
},
{
  "history_date": "24.05.2021, 8:52",
  "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
},
{
  "history_date": "23.05.2021, 6:52",
  "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
}]
```

Пробую выполнить это так:

```
data = [
    {"history_date": "23.05.2021, 6:52", "history_text": "Такси в ожидании" }, 
    {"history_date": "24.05.2021, 8:52", "history_text": "Такси в ожидании" }, 
    {"history_date": "25.05.2021, 9:52", "history_text": "Такси в ожидании" }
] 

for i in data:     
    x = i['history_date']     
    # sorted([datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y.%m.%d, %H:%M") for dt in data])     
    res = sorted(data, key=x)     
    print(i)     

print(res)
```

Пробую выполнить это так.

```
data = [{
  "history_date": "23.05.2021, 6:52",
  "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
},
{
  "history_date": "24.05.2021, 8:52",
  "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
},
{
  "history_date": "25.05.2021, 9:52",
  "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
}]
for i in data:
    x = i['history_date']
    #sorted([datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y.%m.%d, %H:%M") for dt in data])
    res = sorted(data, key=i)
    print(i)
    print(res)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Или без выделения функции, через лямбду:

```
from datetime import datetime

data.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.get('history_date'), '%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M'), reverse=True)
```

теперь в `data`:

```
>>> data
[{'history_date': '25.05.2021, 9:52', 'history_text': 'Такси в ожидании'},
 {'history_date': '24.05.2021, 8:52', 'history_text': 'Такси в ожидании'},
 {'history_date': '23.05.2021, 6:52', 'history_text': 'Такси в ожидании'}]
```

Обратите внимание, что sort в отличие от sorted изменяет исходный список.

Answer (score 4):

Алгоритм решения:

1. напишите функцию `get_date(dict_)`, которая принимает на вход один аргумент - элемент списка и возвращает значение по ключу `history_date` в виде объекта типа `datetime`. Пример элемента: `{"history_date": "23.05.2021, 6:52", "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"}`
2. укажите функцию `get_date` в качестве ключа сортировки: `res = sorted(data, key=get_date, reverse=True)`

Пример решения:

```
from datetime import datetime as DT

def get_date(x, format="%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M"):
    return DT.strptime(x.get("history_date"), format)

res = sorted(data, key=get_date, reverse=True)
```

Проверка:

```
In [136]: data = [{
     ...:   "history_date": "23.05.2021, 6:52",
     ...:   "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
     ...: },
     ...: {
     ...:   "history_date": "24.05.2021, 8:52",
     ...:   "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
     ...: },
     ...: {
     ...:   "history_date": "01.01.1970, 0:00",
     ...:   "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
     ...: }]

In [137]: res = sorted(data, key=get_date, reverse=True)

In [138]: res
Out[138]:

[
  {'history_date': '24.05.2021, 8:52', 'history_text': 'Такси в ожидании'},
  {'history_date': '23.05.2021, 6:52', 'history_text': 'Такси в ожидании'},
  {'history_date': '01.01.1970, 0:00', 'history_text': 'Такси в ожидании'},
]
```

Comment: Пробую выполнить это таким методом.
`data = [{
  "history_date": "23.05.2021, 6:52",
  "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
},
{
  "history_date": "24.05.2021, 8:52",
  "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
},
{
  "history_date": "25.05.2021, 9:52",
  "history_text": "Такси в ожидании"
}]
for i in data:
    x = i['history_date']
    #sorted([datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y.%m.%d, %H:%M") for dt in data])
    res = sorted(data, key=str(x))
    print(i)
    print(res)`
Получаю ошибку. TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @RustamAksenov, перенесите пожалуйста этот код в тело вопроса, воспользовавшись кнопкой ["править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1287045/edit) (под вопросом)

Comment: @RustamAksenov у вас время = часы:минуты или минуты:секунды?

Comment: @MaxU Поправил главный вопрос.

Comment: @Jack_oS часы минуты.

Comment: @RustamAksenov и сортировка в примерах - по убыванию... так и должно быть (сначала - более свежая дата, в конце - старые)?

Comment: @Jack_oS Да с возможностью изменить, старые-новые, новые-старые.

Comment: @MaxU А что должно передоваться в переменной x?
Я пробую выпонить этот код, но получаю тот же список в том же порядке.

Comment: @RustamAksenov, вам нужна обратная сортировка (по убыванию)?

Comment: res = sorted(data, key=get_date, reverse=True), True на False (или убрать reverse) - по возрастанию

Comment: @Jack_oS, спасибо за правку! 

Answer (score -1):

Решил так. True меняем на False.
Регулируя сортировку по возрастанию-убыванию.

```
print(sorted(data, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['history_date'], '%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M'), reverse=True))
```

Comment: "решил так" - это значит воспользовались одним из полученных ответов? Ну тогда и отметьте этот ответ как "верный" - галка слева от [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1287071/211923)

Comment: @MaxU Вы сможете принять свой ответ через 2 дня. :)

Comment: Т.е. вы все-таки хотите принять "свой" ответ, вместо того, которым вы в итоге воспользовались? ;)